# Character Grid in Verbatim/Listing/Etc

Tags: listings, grids

I have a block of text in a framed listing.
I want to draw a faint grid over the listing such that each character in the listing occupies a grid square.

Is there a way to do this without more-or-less reimplementing the listings package using TikZ? That's all I can think of to accomplish this at the moment.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{frame=single}

\begin{document}
  \begin{lstlisting}
    I want these characters to live inside grid rectangles.
  \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```